# How to give time interval for 'for loop' in java android

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I know that the question is simple,but i'm confused.

I have a list of array.I want to iterate it with a **for loop**.On each excecution for doing a particular purpose inside the loop i want to ****wait the loop for 10 sec**** for the next excecution.

Please Help Me

Comment: @shreyanshjogi dont mind,can u show me an example

Comment: using thread.sleep is not good , should use sheduler task in android

Answer (score 3):

You can use timer class of android to perform task at regular interval

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

Details

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
   @Override
   public void run() {
         method(); // call your method
   }
}, 0, 100000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thread.sleep(10000);`

```
for(String s: stringArray){
   try{
         Thread.sleep(10000);
   catch(InterruptedException ie){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(iterate array){
    try{
         Thread.sleep(10000);
    catch(InterruptedException ie){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep()` will do what you want but is not recommended for any serious programming tasks.

`Timer` is much better than Thread.sleep() but is still not the best solution as it uses one Thread per Timer and Timer has a lot of limitations.

You are much better using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example

```
String arr[]=new String[]{"a","b","c"};
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(arr[i]);}
catch(Exception e)
{}
    }
```